# Add UIPickerView to a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to add a `UIPickerVivew` to a `UIAlertController`. I tried to do the following:

```
- (void)alertPickerView    
{    
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:nil    
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil    
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    actionSheet.delegate = self;
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
}
```

When I called the method, the `pickerView` and `actionSheet` didn't come up.

(I would rather a `UIAlertController`, but if that's not possible, I'll go with a `actionsheet`.)

Comment: Do you want a UIAlertController or UIActionSheet? There is a difference. Your statement says your trying to add it to a UIAlertController but your code is for UIActionSheet

Comment: Ok. Well you code is for UIActionSheet so you should probably change it. Additionally you haven't presented the UIActionSheet to the view in general. But to answer your question, this isn't possible. Apple has changed their view hierarchy for UIActionSheets so you can't add subviews to them. Just create your own UIView and present it  it's pretty simple.

Comment: How about a UIActionSheet

Comment: Nope. Read the comment again 'changed hierarchy for UIActionSheets', so this isn't going to translate for UIAlertControllers since UIActionSheets are deprecated for iOS8+.

Comment: I meant, How about a UIAlertView

Comment: I have not tested this but the docs specifically state :`The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified` so you run the risk of rejection. Just go with safe and secure and create your own

Comment: don't be scared to create your own. Its not as code heavy as you think

Comment: Wright, but the thing is, I'm gonna have to change the size when the iphone goes into landscape mode

Comment: You can do that with auto layout or from code. Test your skills, learn something new, it's a good thing.

Comment: @soulshined `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController` are different classes.

Comment: Yes I am fully aware of that. I think the OP is confused @trick14 thats why I said if its not going to work for UIActionSheet it clearly isn't going to work for UIAlertController since it's deprecated at that point